# Magento 2: Static JS Files require-js wrong path

Tags: requirejs, magento2

I'm getting JS errors for files not found in my Magento 2.2.4 installation.
I just upgraded from version 2.1.4 so it's a huge upgrade.

The server makes requests to my static folder and then in specific the language_LANGUAGE folder.

For example:

```
/static/frontend/Infortis/atvise/nl_NL/ultramegamenu.js 404 ()
```

It makes the request to the wrong path...
The file is not in the root directory of nl_NL but in an underlying folder:

```
/static/frontend/Infortis/atvise/nl_NL/Infortis_UltraMegamenu/js/ultramegamenu.js
```

In the requirejs-config.js it states for this specific example:

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'ultramegamenu': 'Infortis_UltraMegamenu/js/ultramegamenu'
},
shim: {
    'ultramegamenu': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'enquire', 'uaccordion']
    }
}
};
```

So that seems to be correct...

Anyone has a clue where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

There is some missing info. Where/how are you initializing your JS component? From a module or theme?

Magento is trying to find the JS file in the root directory because you are requiring it using that path somewhere.

Lets suppose your JS component is in your theme and your `require` instruction is in a `.phtml` file. Surely you are doing it this way:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        require(['ultramegamenu']);
    </script>
...
```

If you change your code to this, I'll work:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        require(['js/ultramegamenu']);
    </script>
...
```

Please note the `js/`/. With this, `require.js` will try to find the script at into the js folder of your theme.